# Retorno falso em uma entrada de números verdadeira?

Tags: python-3.x, lógica

```
TamanhoDoVetor = int(input("Tamanho do vetor ? "))
print()
Vetor = [0] * TamanhoDoVetor

def CriaVetor(VetorNumeros,Tamanho):
    for i in range(Tamanho):
        VetorNumeros[i] = str(input("Elemento do vetor posição " + str (i+1) + " ? "))
def NumerosEstaoEmOrdemCrescente(VetorOriginal,Tamanho):
    Resultado = True
    for a in range(Tamanho):
        b = a + 1
        if a == Tamanho - 1:
            b = a
        if VetorOriginal[a] > VetorOriginal[b]:
            Resultado = False


    if Resultado == False:
         print("Os elementos do seu vetor não se encontra em ordem crescente")
    else:
        print("Os elementos do seu vetor encontra-se em ordem crescente")
CriaVetor(Vetor,TamanhoDoVetor)
NumerosEstaoEmOrdemCrescente(Vetor,TamanhoDoVetor)
```

nesse código acima eles serve para saber se os números de um vetor estão em ordem crescente, se o tamanho do meu vetor for menor ou igual a 9 e as entradas forem em ordem crescente tipo: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 respectivamente o resultado é verdadeiro, porem se meu vetor for de tamanho 10 ou maior, e minha entrada de números for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 respectivamente o resultado e falso, porem como dar pra ver o resultado é verdadeiro pois eles estão em ordem crescente, mas o código me retorna falso. não consigo identificar o erro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente o problema está nessa linha :

```
VetorNumeros[i] = str(input("Elemento do vetor posição " + str (i+1) + " ? "))
```

Que faz com que seu vetor de números seja um vetor de strings e por consequência nessa linha:

```
if VetorOriginal[a] > VetorOriginal[b]:
```

...você faça comparação entre `string` e os respectivos códigos `ASCII` de seus caracteres e não a comparação entre inteiros que deseja fazer.

Tabela ASCII para os números de 0 até 9:

```
Caractere   Dec  Oct    Hex
   0         48  0060   0x30
   1         49  0061   0x31
   2         50  0062   0x32
   3         51  0063   0x33
   4         52  0064   0x34
   5         53  0065   0x35
   6         54  0066   0x36
   7         55  0067   0x37
   8         56  0070   0x38
   9         57  0071   0x39
```

Quando tenta ordenar o vetor `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` em seu programa na verdade está tentando ordenar o vetor `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]` e na ultima comparação:

```
"9" > "10"
```

É uma comparação de strings e é feita em python caractere por caractere, no caso o código ascii de `9` e o  código ascii de `1` :

```
0x39 > 0x31
```

Outros exemplos com a mesma situação:

```
>>> '9' > '1'
True
>>> '9' > '10'
True
>>> '9' > '100'
True
>>> '9' > '1000'
True
>>> '9' > '10000'
True
```

Para corrigir o funcionamento basta alterar a linha :

```
VetorNumeros[i] = str(input("Elemento do vetor posição " + str (i+1) + " ? "))
```

para:

```
VetorNumeros[i] = int(input("Elemento do vetor posição " + str (i+1) + " ? "))
```

Código funcionando:

```
TamanhoDoVetor = int(input("Tamanho do vetor ? "))
print()
Vetor = [0] * TamanhoDoVetor

def CriaVetor(VetorNumeros,Tamanho):
    for i in range(Tamanho):
        VetorNumeros[i] = int(input("Elemento do vetor posição " + str (i+1) + " ? "))
def NumerosEstaoEmOrdemCrescente(VetorOriginal,Tamanho):
    Resultado = True
    for a in range(Tamanho):
        b = a + 1
        if a == Tamanho - 1:
            b = a      
        if VetorOriginal[a] > VetorOriginal[b]:
            Resultado = False


    if Resultado == False:
         print("Os elementos do seu vetor não se encontra em ordem crescente")
    else:
        print("Os elementos do seu vetor encontra-se em ordem crescente")
CriaVetor(Vetor,TamanhoDoVetor)
NumerosEstaoEmOrdemCrescente(Vetor,TamanhoDoVetor)
```

Código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ForkedUntriedDatamining)

Comment: Obrigado cara, passei o dia todo a tentar resolver esse problema, porém sem sucesso ate agora, copiei essa parte do código de outra questão, essa parte quese encontrava o erro, e estava tentando procurar o erro dentro da outra função!